# Need scrollable tab view in react native

Tags: react-native

I am looking for a component with scrollable tab view, as shown below.

[image: Next and previous tab should be faded]

Can any one help me to find such example?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Scrollable Tab View for React Native [Github](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view)

Comment: Thanks. How can I design tab bar as shown in image? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could uese two scroll views.

The first one you use the horizontal prop, and wrap the other scroll view.